# Google Places API error for Android: PLACES_API_QUOTA_FAILED

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have an Android app with several thousands daily active users and the Google Places search API is pretty essential to the user experience.

I started getting quota related errors for my Android app recently.

I noticed the issue on December 2nd.

I had **NOT** configured billing for my Google Developer console before December 2nd and my limit was supposedly 1000 requests per day, but I was usually getting 80/90k requests per day without being throttled, so I never configured billing.
When I saw I was getting this error I decided to configure billing to raise my quota limit to 150k daily.
After raising the limit the search started working again.
However on December 3rd it went down again even though I was way below the 150k limit.

Here is my quota usage page for reference (the red line was at the bottom of the graph before I enabled billing and requests were not being limited):
[image]

Any answer to any of those questions would be highly appreciated if anybody knows...

- Do Android apps actually have unlimited quota for Google Places API?
- Has Google changed anything recently for their quota calculation or has anybody else experienced the same issue?
- Did it happen to anybody to get the "PLACES_API_QUOTA_FAILED" error from their Android app without exceeding the quota?
- I remember reading somewhere on some Google official doc that Android apps had unlimited quotas for Places search but I can't find it anywhere anymore. Anybody knows if that was actually ever the case or if it changed?
- I'm a little confused about this rate limit enforcement policy, since the problem happened again on December 3rd when I was far from the quota limit (around 74k/150k). Anybody has ever been throttled without reaching close to the limit?

Answer (score 0):

THere's more than one quota-  there's a calls per second quota as well as a per day quota.  Maybe you missed the other one?

And no, Android does not have unlimited Places quota.  I don't believe it ever has.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If there is no unlimited quota I don't understand how my 1k quota limit was able to keep working for months but maybe they just started to effectively enforce it. The per second quota is supposed to be per user for some other Google APIs namely "Queries per 100 seconds per user" but for the places API it just says "Queries per day" so I think that's not why...